# Wordpress Audio tag problem in Chrome

Tags: audio

I have been writing a wordpress blog for about 4 years now and only in the last few months have I had a problem with using [AUDIO] tags.  I embed audio using a tag such as [audio src="http://www.hellaholler.com/ouchacha/mp3/163.mp3"].  This has worked well for 4 years.  But in the last few months, when using Google Chrome, the application is not responsive (doesn't play when you click on the triangle), such as it would act if there is no file at the address given.  It works fine when using Microsoft Edge.  Does anyone know why this would be happening all of a sudden?  You can see an example at https://ouchacha.wordpress.com/2016/10/01/melechotech-era-mado/